# Vuex State - Array empty

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

My Problem is, that the state-variable "genreRankings" in "store.js" is never updating.
Can somebody tell me why?

I'm accessing the Store via my Component as follows:

```
saveMovie (item) {
  this.$store.dispatch('addMovie', item).then(x => {
    console.log(this.$store.state.savedMovies)
    this.$store.commit('update_genreRankings', Util.getGenreRankings(this.$store.getters.savedMovies))
  })
},

removeMovie (item) {
  this.$store.dispatch('removeMovie', item).then(x => {
    this.$store.commit('update_genreRankings', Util.getGenreRankings(this.$store.getters.savedMovies))
  })
},
```

Here is store.js (https://gist.github.com/oaltena/ccc70c06c29a1d9af6aa3234aba79518) and Util.js (https://gist.github.com/oaltena/67b8431199e9a6d74681c04d9183e630).

When i access the "genreRankings" via VueDevTools the array is always empty.

Help, please! :-)

Comment: Additional Info: "savedMovies" is not empty but filled with test data from the localstorage.

Comment: Had any luck solving this problem? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try "replacing" the state with a new array :

```
 state.savedMovies = state.savedMovies.concat(object)
```

As written in the Vuex documentation, the state of Vuex store follows the same rules as the state in the components : https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules

PS: it's pretty ugly to call mutations directly from the components, use mapActions to map your actions in your components, then call `commit` from the action. You'll make a more maintenable code.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing this:

```
update_genreRankings (state, object) {
  state.genreRankings = object
}
```

with this:

```
update_genreRankings (state, object) {
  Vue.set(state, 'genreRankings', object)
}
```

Reference: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats